# How can I search and replace by post type?

Tags: wp-cli

I am trying to use WP-CLI to do a search and replace on about 10,000 posts that were imported from another CMS and it has a great deal of old inline styles and spans and such. I would like to be able to use the search and replace function to remove a lot of chaff using regex. I have no issue creating the regex or limiting my command to just the content column in the wp_posts table, but I do not see a built in way way to limit my `post_type` to only `post`, not `page` or others that are in the `wp_posts` table. Is there one?

Here is a code example:

`wp search-replace '<span^.*>' '' --regex wp_posts --include-columns=post_content`

Comment: Please share the commands you have put together, so that others can review and give suggestions.

Comment: I added it. So do you know how to use this to filter by post type?

Comment: And for more info, I am doing multiple passes on the DB, one to remove the `<span>` and another to remove the `</span>`, likely I will end up writing a php script that handles the post type filter and run my wp-cli command entry by entry in a loop if there is no way to filter the post type as part of my command line command.

Comment: Sounds like a [feature request](https://github.com/wp-cli/search-replace-command/issues/125) to me. Sounds also that this probably should be more of a `post update` command then. See the linked issue on GitHub, this may be done via `wp db cli` and then `update wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'before', 'after') where post_type = 'page';` maybe.